# Embedding 2500 images into feature class using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, image, attachments

How can I automate embedding images into a feature class attribute table?

I am working with a point feature class within a geodatabase that has a total of 2500 rows of data that need two image attachments each. Each row has a unique ID that corresponds with the image (Labeled by ID) that needs to be tied to it. I am working within ArcMap 10.4.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate attachments using ModelBuilder. For more information about attachments and the various tools you can use visit [An overview of the Attachments toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-attachments-toolset.htm).

The tools in the Attachments toolset require an ArcGIS for Desktop *Standard* or *Advanced* license.